# Laravel Eloquent/DB getting relation by foreign table and order results

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

In **Laravel 5.5** I have a database setup like the ERD image below. I prefer using Eloquent over Query Builder but I'm not sure it can be done by Eloquent.

[image]

**Relationships**

- Object A -> Object B [one - one to many]
- Object B -> Object C [one - one]

---

**How would I do the following:** Start the query with  Object A. Through Object A I want to obtain Object(s) B and though Object B I want to obtain the corresponding Object C. The last thing that is required is that the results will be sorted Ascending by the `position` column in Object B.

**What I've tried myself:** With Eloquent get Object A and all Objects of B *(this is sorted Ascending on position)*. Foreach Object of B seek corresponding Object C. But I know this is not the best solution for the problem.

Any advise?

Comment: it is definitely possible, read up on https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

Comment: @pseudoanime Thanks for the reference. I have read that page multiple times but which part of the documentation would you prefer using for this scenario?

Comment: Take a look at nested eager loading in the page. $results = ObjectA::with('ObjectB.ObjectC)->get(); will give you all the 3 objects. Then it's just a matter of sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**With help of you guys I came to the best solution I could think off:**

```
ObjectA::with(['ObjectB' => function($query){
    $query->orderBy('position', 'asc');
},'ObjectB.ObjectC'])->get();
```

**ObjectA Model**

```
public function ObjectB()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ObjectB');
}
```

**ObjectB Model**

```
public function ObjectC()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\ObjectC');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with eager loading.

Something like:

```
$result = $ObjectA->with(['ObjectB', 'ObjectB.ObjectC'])->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: This only works if ObjectA has a direct relationship with ObjectC right? But ObjectA has a relationship through ObjectB with ObjectC.

Answer (score 1):

I updated the previous comment by Gerson where my edit should be visible until reviewed, but here is how i would do it:

```
$result = $ObjectA->with(['ObjectB', 'ObjectB.ObjectC'])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Eloquent

```
 $data['result'] = ObjectA::join('ObjectB','ObjectA.id','=','ObjectB.object_a_id')
->join('ObjectC','ObjectB.id','=','ObjectC.object_b_id')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks this works but two things I notice: 1. You forgot `->orderBy('position', 'asc')` and 2. I don't have the information of ObjectA anymore. Would like to atleast have the id of objectA with all the info from the other objects. I need all fields from all tables so a join wouldn't be so bad.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would probably try to do:

```
$ObjectA->with('ObjectB.ObjectC')
    ->join('ObjectB','ObjectA.id','=','ObjectB.object_a_id')
    ->orderBy('ObjectB.position','asc')
    ->get();
```